# Make bootstrap carousel directly below navbar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Currently on my website I use the bootstrap navbar that's always at the top of the screen (even when you scroll).

Right below it I have an image carousel which is pushed below it by giving the page top padding to push it below.

The problem is that this is mostly guesswork as the height of the navbar changes with font sizes, on my high font size it overlaps the carousel, but on lower font sizes it's fine.

Is there a way to make it so the carousel is directly below the navbar without a gap, and if the navbar gets bigger due to bigger fonts to push it down more? I never want there to be an overlap or a gap.

It's not an issue with a normal navbar as the elements would just sit after eachother, but as this is the navbar-fixed-top it makes it a bit akward.

Url: http://www.gamingonlinux.com/

Code:

```
<!-- navbar -->
<div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top {:inverse}" role="navigation">
          <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                  <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                  <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                  <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                  <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
              </div>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li><a href="/" style="padding-top: 0px; padding-bottom: 0px;"><img src="/templates/default/images/navbar_logo_{:theme}.png" alt="GamingOnLinux" /></a></li>
                    <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/donate/">Donate</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/sales/">Sales</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/contact-us/">Submit Tip</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/crowdfunding/">Wiki</a></li>
                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Forum <b class="caret"></b></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                            <li><a href="/forum/">Forum</a></li>
                            <li><a href="/community/">Community Page</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> {:username} <b class="caret"></b></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                            {:user_menu}
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span><b class="caret"></b></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                            <li><form method="get" action="/index.php?module=search" class="navbar-form" role="search">
                    <input type="hidden" name="module" value="search">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="q" placeholder="Search Articles">
                    <input type="submit" style="position: absolute; left: -9999px; width: 1px; height: 1px;"/>
                </form></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="row add-bottom-margin">
                <!-- image carousel -->
                <div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
                      <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
                      <div class="carousel-inner">
                       {:carousel_list}
                      </div>

                      <!-- Controls -->
                      <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide="prev">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
                      </a>
                      <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide="next">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
                      </a>
                </div><!-- /.carousel -->
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: I don't understand why you can't just add `margin: 2px;` to the top of the carousel? do you plan to change the fonts dynamically somehow or are you trying to account for browser zoom in/out?

Comment: Reading though your question I was only able to have a white space show below your navigation menu when I did a browser zoom to 125% or more. If this was your issue a simple fix of adding a height to the navbar class seemed to fix this problem.

Comment: You absolutely don't need col-md-12 on your content since it's full width and you don't need a row either. If it's full width inside a .container, you don't use the grid system

Comment: Thank you Christina I had no idea! That will clean up my code a bit!

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer elsewhere, instead of forcing a specific gap, calculate it with js and set it:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    $('.contentwrap').css({
        'margin-top': (($('.navbar-fixed-top').height()) + 0) + 'px'
    });
    $(window).resize(function () {
        $('.contentwrap').css({
            'margin-top': (($('.navbar-fixed-top').height()) + 0) + 'px'
        });
    });
});
```